# How to store record into two different databases using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a two databases:

1. first
2. second

Both database have a same tables:

Database name: first

```
    tables:
      1. area
      2. group
```

Database name: second

```
    tables:
      1. area
      2. group
```

so i want to saving record into both database at same time using php.

Comment: Okay, so do that. You either set up 2 connections, or you can potentially specify the database and table in the insert, e.g. `INSERT INTO databasename.tablename` if they're on the same db server.

Comment: is it possible with one insert query or not?

Comment: No, it's not possible in a single query. Not even sure why you'd want to.

Comment: Sir i want to backup into another database

Comment: Right? Why does that mean it has to be done in a single query? There are loads of mysql backup options. Google it.

Answer (score 0):

2 databases meaning two separate database servers? 
If so, make 2 separate connections and then do inserts accordingly.

Using mysqli, it will look something like this

```
//Connection to database 1
$con1=mysqli_connect("xxxxx:portno","database","username","password");

//Connection to database 2
$con2=mysqli_connect("xxxxx:portno","database","username","password");

$sql_table1= "INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...)";
$sql_table2= "INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...)";

if ($con1->query($sql_table1) === TRUE) {

    echo "Values inserted successfully in table 1 of db1"; 

} 

else {


echo "Error in insertion";


}

if ($con2->query($sql_table2) === TRUE) {

    echo "Values inserted successfully in table 2 of db2"; 

} 

else {


echo "Error in insertion";


}
```